# How can I defeat Wiggler and Kamek?

Tags: mario-and-luigi-paper-jam

I've played this fight about ten times now, 8 of those on Easy Mode, and I can't beat this fight. Wiggler gets POW increases right away, and his attacks seem to basically one-hit my guys. I can't leave the fight and come back, so I am limited to the 3 1UP mushrooms and 5 Double 1UP mushrooms I have plus a few other items.

I can't seem to beat this fight, and I am really tired of being here. I know the hints say to stun Wiggler so you can hit Kamek, and to watch Kamek's attacks so you can bounce them back to hit Wiggler, but I don't seem to even get far enough to use these hints to figure out, say, how to stun Wiggler, etc.

How can I defeat Wiggler and finally get past this fight?

Comment: Learn to dodge, and stop getting hit.

Comment: @Seiyria that's completely unhelpful.

Comment: As for your actual questions: to stun wiggler, you need to get to a certain point in the fight by dodging attacks and dealing damage to him. The only way to hit Kamek is deal about 460 damage to Wiggler, and then you get about 1 or 2 rounds with Kamek. It should take 3-4 rounds to kill Kamek - less if you dodge all of the enemy attacks. My point is still the same - you need to dodge his attacks or you will not beat this fight.

Comment: "I can't leave the fight and come back" - why not? Did you just forget to save for a while, so you'd lose a bunch of progress if you abandoned the fight?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. And I don't want to redo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having issues with this fight as well.  These are some tips I think will be helpful.

- Keep Paper Mario alive! If one of the regular brothers falls, it's a pain trying to dodge with the other supporting.  Paper Mario will never have to support a fallen ally and his ability to clone makes for easier survival.
- When Kamek is shooting "magic" watch where each color goes. I find watching shadows is particularly helpful. The color will always go to the same character during that attack. So, if orange goes to Luigi, then the next time orange comes up be watching Luigi.
- For the mud ball wiggler shoots, paper Mario always had multiples, so you need to float over them all while the other 2 get one big ball to jump over. This attack is fairly easy to dodge.
- The hardest attack for me was the waves wiggler sent out after stomping. Watch normal Mario and as close to the last second as you can get, dodge with all 3 characters, keeping the buttons held so Paper Mario floats up enough to clear it. There **will** be a second wave shortly after so always be prepared for 2.
- Another pretty annoying attack is when wiggler stands tall and begins chasing one character. Let that character run until you are within hammer range of the mole. Quickly hit it then keep running until the shy guy starts from the left. Hit it with your hammer and continue. There will be a second shy guy for you to hit, them Kamek who is a bit faster then the shy guy but same strategy.
- the last attack I remember is when Paper Mario is used as a boomerang with wiggler chasing toward the screen on a ball. Aim quickly and err on the side of not missing. I always assumed toward the side of the ball closer to the middle so if it moves you'll still hit. After a few hits, you should be safe.
- Don't be afraid to use your battle cards when you can and flip over ones that aren't helping you so new ones can replace them.  Also, brother and trio attacks are great for high damage.
- Seriously, it's OK for the non-paper heroes to be down for a while.  It's much easier to focus on one character when dodging and I find Paper Mario tends to do a better job at surviving a hit, what with his copy ability. If necessary, you can keep using copy and going through dodge with him to get timing down for the various attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I just got to wiggaler and the trick is to ignore wiggaler all you have to do with him is counter-attacking. The real problem is kamek whenever they (wiggaler and kamek) team up, only focus on kamek if you can defeat kamek the spell will come off wiggaler!

PS: If you're good at this point in the game and you can control Mario and Luigi and Paper Mario. If you saved the game right before you battled wiggaler. If you lost the battle go to a power up store and get as many double up mushrooms as possible.You need those because if two bros fall down use them. And make sure the only bros that you let fall down are Mario and Luigi and if your good with not letting them faint then ignore this.
 Well see ya gamers........BOOOOOM